# What is the correct way to hide HTML elements on page load before they are displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, hide

I have found numerous partial answers to this question, but nothing that seems like a definitive answer. For such an important technique I find this a little strange.

How should I hide elements (using javascript) so that they do not appear briefly when the page loads before the JS has a chance to hide them? I don't want to set them to hidden initially with CSS as if a user doesn't have Javascript, they will see nothing.

To be clear. I'm not asking how to handle displaying content to users who don't have JS. That is an entirely different subject. I just want a reliable way to hide HTML elements before they are displayed.

So my requirements:

1. HTML elements are not hidden initially using CSS
2. If JS is available, these elements are hidden so that they are never displayed, not even for an instant. This means hiding them from JS loaded at the end of the body is out).

Comment: Sounds like two separate issues.  First, how do you hide elements initially, and secondly what do you do if clients don't have javascript (enabled).  Careful not to make these one question.

Comment: I think maybe using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) would help. You still can specify using CSS to hide elements, so for browsers without javascript, you can use `.no-js` class to override the styles to display them. But I'm not so sure about the initial "flashing" of elements being displayed. That's to do with how code is structured and how web browsers parses and displays them.

Comment: @Erik Philips. I only mention that requirement to avoid receiving answers like 'set the elements to display:hidden' in your stylesheet.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like VKen, I prefer to use [moderizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [Paul Irish's structure for the `html` element](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) (which is what [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in the style sheet:

```css
.element-to-hide { display: none; }

.no-js .element-to-hide { display: block; }
```

Works great, no flash of elements disappearing.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use javascript to include an optional CSS file in which you hide those divs.

Put this in your `HEAD` section :

```
<script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hiding.css"/>');</script>
```

And in hiding.css :

```
div.mySelector {
   display:none;
}
```

If you don't have additional css to set, you may also more simply inline the css rule in javascript (still in the HEAD) :

```
<script>
document.write('<style type="text/css">div.mySelector {display:none; }</style>');
</script>
```

If Javascript isn't available, the divs won't be hidden.
And if it is available, the CSS will be used to hide the div before they're displayed.

Comment: Thanks. What is the browser support for this approach?

Comment: I use CSS link generation in javascript in all modern browsers and I don't see why there would be incompatibilities in older ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use a descendent combinator and make the body a member of a class as soon as possible.

```
<style>
    /* js only element */
    .js foo { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script> document.body.className += " js"; </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is this JS guaranteed to be run before the page is rendered?

Comment: This is actually my preferred method. It gets ran immediately, as it's not dependent on loading any library and is one of the simplest solutions. I've never experienced issues using this method.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a `<noscript>` tag and overwrite the initial css for those with javascript disabled