# how can i have some fields shown in rails forms based on the user selection of previous fields?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, field, partials

this is the code iam using.

```
<%= form_for(@shift) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Does_This_Shift_Have_a_Break? %></br> 
    <%= f.radio_button :shift_break_option, 'Yes' %> Yes
    <%= f.radio_button :shift_break_option, 'No' %> No<br />
  </div>

   <div id="break_dur_fields">  
     <div class="field">  
       <%= f.label :Do_you_want_to_deduct_the_break_duration?%></br> 
       <%= f.radio_button :break_deduction_option, 'Yes' %> Yes
       <%= f.radio_button :break_deduction_option, 'No' %> No<br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :What_is_the_break_start_time? %> </br> 
    <%= f.select :break_start_hrs, (1..12).map { |i| "%02d" % i } %>  <%= f.select :break_start_min, (0..59).map { |i| "%02d" % i } %>
    <%= f.select :break_start_am_pm, options_for_select([["AM", "AM"], ["PM", "PM"]], :selected => @shift.break_start_am_pm) %></br>
   </div>
   <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :What_is_the_break_end_time?%></br> 
    <%= f.select :break_end_hrs, (1..12).map { |i| "%02d" % i } %>  <%= f.select :break_end_min, (0..59).map { |i| "%02d" % i } %>
    <%= f.select :break_end_am_pm, options_for_select([["AM", "AM"], ["PM", "PM"]], :selected => @shift.break_end_am_pm) %></br>
   </div>  

  </div> 

  <div class="field">  
   <%= f.label :the_shift_duration_is %>

   <%= f.text_field :duration ,:readonly => true, :size=>"4",:value => (f.object.duration || 0 ) %> &nbsp;minutes.

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here i want to show the div(i.e., break_dur_fields) section only when a user clicks a particular radio button on the form. currently by using jquery iam hiding this div section. and when the user clicks a particular radio button then only iam showing this div section by using jquery. but this kind of approach is not the way to implement this it seams. as in this the fields are firstly appearing and immeadiately disappearing as iam hiding with jquery. i donot want this kind of effect.so here i want to dynamically render a partial by using javascipt that contain this particular div fields when the user clicks a particular radio button on the page by using javascript. how can i implement this?

Comment: I would do this in `jQuery` as you have done.  You can update your post with your code if it is not working properly.

Comment: it is working fine. but when the page loads initially the fields are displaying. and immeadiately those are disappearing. it is not good looking. i dont want this kind of effect.

Comment: OK I understand.  Researching myself as I have a similar issue on one of my pages.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863544/what-is-the-correct-way-to-hide-html-elements-on-page-load-before-they-are-displ?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but couldn't make it work for me.  I think my issue may just be tied to my dev env which is very slow although I may try to do change my implementation to hide through CSS.

Comment: I don't know how to do that @Prashanth.  From everything I've read, it is either `jQuery` or `CSS`.  Of course, you can use `AJAX` to do it, but that might be a little overkill.

Comment: I gotta jet but I just fixed mine with CSS.  Seems like it should be fine.

Comment: i implemented this fields in a partial and tried rendering this partial dynamically  when a particular radio button clicked by using js. by using the syntax like this   $("#div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/pro/users/show_partial'}) %>");  but iam getting the error undefined variable "f". can we do in this way?

Comment: You can use `fields_for` on partial and pass `@object` to it via js

Comment: @anonymousxxx how can we have access rails object in js? and what about the edit form of this page ? will these partial fields populated from the database in the case of edit form? if possible try to post sample code.

Comment: Yes you can make this work.  I would search "Rails AJAX example" and you should find something.  If you are still stuck later, I'll explain more or answer questions (busy day).